# asp.net validators still posting back

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback

I'm using the default validation that comes with .NET

The problem I am having is that even with JavaScript enabled on my browser, a basic validation is still allowing postback.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

My App is usihg UrlRewriting.Net... could this be the problem?

```
<urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>
        <!--Fix the WebResource JS Error-->
        <add name="WebResourceFix" virtualUrl="^~/WebResource.axd(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" destinationUrl="~/WebResource.axd$1" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <!--Fix the ScriptResource JS Error-->
        <add name="ScriptResource" virtualUrl="^~/ScriptResource.axd(.*)" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" destinationUrl="~/ScriptResource.axd$1" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <!--Allow Extensionless Pages-->
        <add name="pageExtensionless" virtualUrl="^~/(.+)$" redirectMode="Permanent" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/$1.aspx" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `CausesValidation = True` on your button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="True" />
```

Comment: I have never had to do that before.  This is a new one to me.  Usually CausesValidation is enabled by default.

Comment: I agree, that's odd.  I wonder if the textbox is inheriting a "CausesValidation=False" from a container control...

Comment: I don't have any "CausesValidation" anywhere in my site.

Comment: Sorry.. I "Answered" too soon.  Turns out the Google Maps Control I got from CodePlex is causing the validation issues.  Not sure how to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions on debugging problems like this:

1. Use Fiddler or some other HTTP debugger to ensure that the page is correctly downloading the external JavaScript files used to provide client-side validation, and that these client-side files are being correctly returned from the server (that is, that they are not returning 404 or some other HTTP error code).
2. Use Firebug to set a breakpoint and step through the JavaScript execution.

Answer (score 0):

In your RequiredFieldValidator I would suggest that you try setting `EnableClientScript="true"`. Hopefully that will fix the problem.